# hi, i want to fetch some data from an api, the code i write it works but it has delay,it shows when i log it and i use async /await

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch-api, use-effect

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { getProducts } from "../services/api"
import { useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

const ProductDetails = () => {
    
    const params = useParams();
    const id = params.id;
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const data = products[id -1]
    
    useEffect (() => {
        
        const fetchAPII = async () => {
            setProducts(await getProducts());
        }
        
        fetchAPII();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        
        <div>
          {console.log(data)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

and the result log is:
undefined/
undefined
{id: 2, title: 'Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ', price: 22.3, description: 'Slim-fitting style, contrast raglan long sleeve, t…e round neckline includes a three-button placket.', category: "men's clothing", …}

the code works but with delay

Comment: Just putting `{data}` in the div should be enough. If you want to console.log do it in functions not in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

actually it take time to get data from api side. you have to use some loader to make it graceful.